# callback issue in class (does not detect calling a function at the method close)

Tags: javascript, class, asynchronous, callback

I have to create those two functions in the dialog class, and can't figure out what's wrong.

1.onClose - This method will take a callback function as an argument and store it on our Dialog instance.

2.close - This function will be used to close the dialog. When we close the dialog, we'll want to call the callbackFunction.

```
class Dialog {

// constructor(callbackFunction) {
//     stored : this.callbackFunction;
// }
onClose(callbackFunction){
 this.onClose = callbackFunction; // store the callback
  
}

close(callbackFunction) {   
 callbackFunction;// invoke the callback
}
```

}

I keep getting the error "Callback was not called after close".

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all - you don't call the `callbackFunction` anywhere - notice, that calling means: `callbackFunction()` and not just `callbackFunction`.
2. Think about changing the variable name, since there might be some conflicts(both method and variable are named `onClose`
3. Is the `close` function suppose to call the `callbackFunction` assigned to `this.onClose`? If so, then you do not need to pass an argument there, simply call `this.onClose()`.

To sum up, I believe that it should look like this:

```js
class Dialog {


onClose(callbackFunction){
 this.closeFn = callbackFunction; // you have to figure out some other name :)
  
}

close() {   
 this.closeFn();// invoke the callback
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't even realise I wasn't calling the function. The calling of this.closeFn() was what I was doing initially but I thought perhaps the program was passing another function to proof it.